# How to update an axios instance while intercept response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript, request, axios

How to update an axios instance while intercept a response using data from this response without second request? New token can be received in any response after any request. Last received token should be used in any new request.

```
const request = (axios as any).create({
  baseURL: mainConfig.apiBaseUrl,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

// Check token relevance and update if not relevance.
request.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  if (response.headers.token !== undefined) {
    response.config.headers.token = response.headers.token;
  }
  return response;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can't set it for further requests like this.

You should use globalStorage or any other store for storing this token.

```
import Store from "Store";

const request = (axios as any).create({
  baseURL: mainConfig.apiBaseUrl,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': Store.token
  },
});

// Use latest token from store
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    const {token} = Store;
    config.headers.Authorization = token;
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

// Update token in store
request.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  const {token} = response.headers;
  if (token) {
    Store.setToken(token);
  }
  return response;
}
```

Comment: This way, your instance is still only created initially and is not updated after updating the token in the store, as it is not 'observing' the store

Comment: @mahmoudafer You're right. Updated the code for fetching the latest token from store for every new request.